# playing sound files on the iphone/ipod touch

Tags: iphone, audio

What are the recommended formats to play sound files on the iphone/ipod touch devices. I am am developing an application that should be able to play long sound files on the device. Are there any limitations to the size of the sound file and which would be the best and most optimized file size to play on the iphone/ipod touch

Answer (score 1):

Appendix D from the CoreAudio docs covers supported filetypes: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX.html

Answer (score 0):

I think AAC is the preferred compressed audio format for the iPhone / iPod Touch. Plus it has the advantage of being better quality than MP3 at the same bit rate.